# Logging date format misrepresents │as ¦

Tags: python, logging, utf-8

I have a logging script with set formatting. It is using utf-8 symbols for readability, the encoding is set for saving of the files, as seen below.

```
log = logging.getLogger('general')
fmt = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d  │  %(levelname)-10s│  %(lineno)4s %(funcName)-20s│  %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y/%m/%d │ %H:%M:%S')
handler_error = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler("error.log", 'a', encoding="utf-8")
handler_error.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler_error.setFormatter(fmt)
log.addHandler(handler_error)
```

Theoretically, all the separators should be │'s, but the one in *datefmt* it is being changed into ¦. Thus, the resulting log looks like below - notice all the vertical lines added properly except the one set between date and time.

I have tried using unicode *\u2502* instead of │, did not help. Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image: screenshot of the log]

**Edit - an error log from another user's execution.**

```
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1025, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 869, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 610, in format
    record.asctime = self.formatTime(record, self.datefmt)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 548, in formatTime
    s = time.strftime(datefmt, ct)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'locale' codec can't encode character '\u2502' in position 9: encoding error
```

Comment: Works for me.  Have you tried wit different terminals/fonts?

Comment: Yup, different fonts or notepad, which also uses the basic Microsoft font. For me unfortunately these are two different characters. I will try it out on another environment maybe.

Comment: Issue seems to be with logging's locale. For you it works as intended, for me it changes character and for my friend it throws an error ("UnicodeEncodeError: 'locale' codec can't encode character '\u2502' in position 9: encoding error").. I needed to change it to a simple hyphen in order to make it work flawlessly.

I guess it depends on logging/python version? I have 3.8.4, whereas my buddy has 3.7.something.

Comment: Interesting - what is your locale? (en_GB.UTF-8 here)

Comment: Do you mean Windows in general or? For Windows I tried pl_PL and en_US. I have also added the full log from my buddy's execution.

Comment: You need to set `LC_CTYPE` to UTF-8 e.g. as `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_CTYPE, (locale.getlocale(locale.LC_CTYPE)[0], 'utf8'))`

Comment: @JosefZ That actually helped. Importing locale and setting this has helped. Can you add this as a regular answer so I could accept is as solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**: You need to set `LC_CTYPE` to `UTF-8`

The following example for more *Box Drawings* characters shows that there goes some character translation in `datefmt` string (similar to the difference between Windows commands [`tree` vs `tree /A`](https://ss64.com/nt/tree.html)).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time, locale
t = time.localtime()
datefmt = '%Y/%m/%d ─│┌┐└┘├┤┬┴┼═║╔╗╚╝╠╣╦╩╬ %H:%M:%S'
print( '\n datefmt:', datefmt)

print( '\nLC_CTYPE:', locale.getlocale(category=locale.LC_CTYPE) )
print( 'strftime:', time.strftime(datefmt, t) )

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_CTYPE, (locale.getlocale()[0], '1252'))
print( '\nLC_CTYPE:', locale.getlocale(category=locale.LC_CTYPE) )
print( 'strftime:', time.strftime(datefmt, t) )

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_CTYPE, (locale.getlocale()[0], 'utf8'))
print( '\nLC_CTYPE:', locale.getlocale(category=locale.LC_CTYPE) )
print( 'strftime:', time.strftime(datefmt, t) )
```

**Output**: `.\SO\63472673.py`

> ```
>  datefmt: %Y/%m/%d ─│┌┐└┘├┤┬┴┼═║╔╗╚╝╠╣╦╩╬ %H:%M:%S
>
> LC_CTYPE: ('Czech_Czechia', '1250')
> strftime: 2020/08/20 ¦--¬L-++T++=¦-¬L-¦¦T¦+ 19:29:14
>
> LC_CTYPE: ('Czech_Czechia', '1252')
> strftime: 2020/08/20 -¦+++++¦--+-¦++++¦¦--+ 19:29:14
>
> LC_CTYPE: ('Czech_Czechia', 'utf8')
> strftime: 2020/08/20 ─│┌┐└┘├┤┬┴┼═║╔╗╚╝╠╣╦╩╬ 19:29:14
> ```

Unfortunately, I can't find that character translation in Python source code (one can see that there is a bug with (my native) code page `1250`: characters `─` and `│` are translated as `¦` and `-`, respectively i.e.  in the reverse order…